# Py: Как в Skype4Py воспроизвести WAV файл при звонке?

Tags: python

Используя [данный](https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py/blob/master/examples/record.py) скрипт, я не могу воспроизвести звонком свои WAV файлы (записанные через спец. программы / скачанные из интернета), однако файлы, записанные тем же примером, отлично воспроизводятся при звонке. В чем может быть проблема?

Записанный скриптом:

```
PCM, 256 Кбит/сек, 1 канал, 16,0 КГц (Little/Signed)
```

Не работают:

```
ADPCM, 64,0 Кбит/сек, 1 канал, 16,0 КГц (intel)
PCM, 768 Кбит/сек, 1 канал, 48,0 КГц  (Little/Signed)
PCM, 705,6 Кбит/сек, 2 канала, 22,05 КГц (Little/Signed)
```

Comment: Попробуйте сравнить форматы файлов, которые играют и не играют (покажите инфу типа:  Codec: PCM S16 LE (s16l) Channels: Mono Sample rate: 44100 Hz Bits per sample: 16)

Comment: Добавил к посту.

Comment: попробуйте всё в один формат превратить, используя audacity, ffmpeg, итд.

Comment: Я открыл файл, который нормально работает, через audacity, отрендерил его в точно таком же формате (моно, 16кгц, 32бит) и отрендеренный в скрипте не работает, хотя оригинал, повторюсь, прекрасно работает. Магия... Спасибо что пытаетесь помочь.

Comment: 16KHz*32bit=512Kbit/sec а у вас 256Kbit/sec написано. Более вероятно 16 бит, а не 32.

Comment: Попробовал отрендерить разными способами. (signed 16bit PCM, float32bit PCM; MS: Signed 16bit PCM, Signed 32bit PCM, 32bit float; NIST signed 16/32bit; Wavex MS: Signed 32/16bit PCM, 32bit float) Не один файл не работал в скрипте (в муз. проигрывателях все отлично работает).

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Если не работает, значит есть отличия. Также [на размер ограничения до 4MB в Skype for Business](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398649(v=ocs.14).aspx) убедитесь, что без сжатия LPCM, A-Law, или mu-Law формат. Посмотрите какие [разные форматы в wav файлах могут быть](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py/issues/15

Нужно изменить формат с Wave на WAVEFORMATEX

Например скриптом:

```
import sys
import array
import os
def OnText2SpeechGenerateFinished(pData):

    # Open the file, and create a temp file
    pFileIn = open(pData, "rb")
    pFileOut = open(pData + "-convert", "wb")
    pBuf = array.array('B')

    # Read the first 44 bytes and make our modificates
    pBuf.fromfile(pFileIn,0x24)

    pBuf[0x10] +=2 
    pBuf[0x04] +=2 

    pBuf.tofile(pFileOut)
    pFileOut.write(chr(0x00))
    pFileOut.write(chr(0x00))
    pFileOut.flush()

    # Read rest of file
    try:
        while 1:
            pBuf = array.array('B')
            pBuf.fromfile(pFileIn,10000)
            pBuf.tofile(pFileOut)
    except:
        pBuf.tofile(pFileOut)


    pFileIn.close()
    pFileOut.close()

    # Delete Input file

    os.remove(pData)
    os.rename(pData+"-convert",pData)

    # Done
    return True

OnText2SpeechGenerateFinished(sys.argv[1])
```